# Java Canvas white edge

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I'd like to make a `Canvas` based Java application. I've extended my main class to `Canvas` and I size it in it's constructor.

```
public CanvasApp() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(640, 480);
    setSize(size);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
}
```

and in the main function, I make a frame for it, like this:

```
CanvasApp cnv = new CanvasApp();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.setBorder(null); //I've tried this
panel.setSize(640,480); //but still doesn't work =(
panel.add(cnv, BorderLayout.CENTER);

frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

But the content pane appears 650x490 in size. Why is this?

I've attached a picture too.

[I've drew a line from 0,0 to 640,480](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quI1Q.png)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - Don't mix the AWT based `Component` with a Swing GUI.  Use a `JComponent` instead.

Comment: sorry, that was my fault. I made a `Canvas` not `Component` :)

Comment: O...K  In that case, *Don't mix the AWT based **Canvas** with a Swing GUI.  Use..*

Comment: And what'd **You** use instead of `Canvas` for drawing things?

Comment: <head-desk/> Try reading the last sentence of my ***1st comment***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a JFrame has a 5px border around it, look at any frame on your computer screen you'll notice a kind of embossed border - that border is 5 px in width adding 10 pixels onto height and width. You've only assigned the panel to 640 x 480 and plonked it inside the frame - the frame then adds it's own border onto that.

Comment: That was my first thought too. But the panel is 650x490, not the whole thing :(

Comment: JPanel also has a border around it - do cnv.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder())

Comment: I've set the panel border to null, but I can't set the border of a `Canvas`

Comment: No set the border to BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder() sorry I made a mistake there it wasn't meant to be null (I've edited original comment)

Comment: `panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`
but still doesn't work =(

Answer (score 3):

Thats probably because every JComponen have a border, you put your CanvasApp inside JPanel and JPanel itself into JFrame. That is probably the reason why you get bigger dimensions at the end.
See the oracle website on how to use borders here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: I've set the border to null, and resized the panel too, still not working :(